# Transition between 2 movies using a MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to make a smooth cross fade between 2 movies in my iPad App. On a button tap the visuals randomize & the movie which is playing fades to the next movie.

Since 2 movies cannot be played simultaneously (from the docs) a straight-forward cross-fade isn't possible. To get around this I use a still image of the initial frame of the new movie (which is to be faded in). I used two players to handle the interchange of movies.

The original movie is paused, Then I transition to the image. Now I add my 2nd movie (with alpha = 0.0) & then transition so that its alpha = 1. I then play the new movie. This all works ok except for a noticeable darkening as the new movie transitions in over the image.

I tested it without the still image & the darkening doesn't seem to occur during said transition.

My code for the switch is below (first half of the if-statement). It looks pretty strange ,looking over it, but it's the method that brought me closest to what I needed.

Maybe there's a better way to go about this task? Thanks in advance :)

```
- (void) switchMovie;
{

NSURL *movieImageUrl = [movieImageUrlArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieImageUrl];
UIImage *movieImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:movieImage];

image.alpha = 0.0f;
[self addSubview:image];

if (moviePlayer1Playing) {

moviePlayer1Playing = NO;
moviePlayer2Playing = NO;

[moviePlayer1 pause]; //pausing later in the method caused a crash, stopping causes a crash.

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                     image.alpha = 1.0f;             //fade in still of first frame of new movie

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [moviePlayer1 release];   //release original movie.

                     moviePlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[movieUrlArray objectAtIndex:index]]; 

                     moviePlayer2.shouldAutoplay = NO;
                     [moviePlayer2 prepareToPlay];
                     [moviePlayer2 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
                     moviePlayer2.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
                     [moviePlayer2.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024 , 768)];
                     moviePlayer2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                     moviePlayer2.view.alpha = 0.0;
                     [self addSubview:moviePlayer2.view];

                     [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.0 
                                           delay: 0.0 
                                         options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear  
                                      animations:^(void){ 

                                         moviePlayer2.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                                         //During this transition the view goes dark half-way through, before lightening again.

                                      } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

                                          [moviePlayer2 play];
                                          moviePlayer2Playing = YES;  
                                          moviePlayer1Playing = NO;


                                      }];

                 }]; 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The black you see is the background of the movie player, so instead of using a UIImageView for the still, you should set the background of your movie player the desired still.

```
UIImageView *stillImageView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:stillImage];
stillImageView.frame = self.moviePlayer.backgroundView.frame;

[self.moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:stillImageView];
[stillImageView release];
```

Comment: This seems a perfect way to address the problem yet I cannot add the still as a background for my movie. The line: [self.moviePlayer.backgroundView addSubview:stillImageView];
is not implemented - All that I can see is the blue background color (which I set for illustration), the still isn't added over the background color. Is it possible that the processing of large movie files is handled by hardware codecs, thus giving rise to odd behaviour?

Comment: That's odd.  I took the code I posted here from a project with which I have done this before.  I'll try some different variations to see if I can recreate your problem.